# Can you create a new variable using an argument from a function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, arguments

Is it possible to create a new variable with name equal to function argument?

```
var add = function(name, age) {
  var name = age;
}
add('bob', 30);
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but I hope you can see what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Any time you think you need to create variables dynamically, you're probably wrong. You should be using an object to map strings to values.

Comment: No, that won't work, but as @Barmar says, you could do something like: `var object = {};  object[name] = age;` and then access it like `object['bob'];`